# Calculating the eigenenergies of two coupled quantum harmonic oscillators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, eigenvalue, coupled-oscillators

I am trying to calculate what the energy spectrum of two coupled quantum harmonic oscillators look like but didn't know the steps to take in order to do this, I have a Hamiltonian of the form:

$$H = \omega_a \hat a^\dagger \hat a +\omega_b \hat b^\dagger \hat b + V(\hat a^\dagger \hat b + \hat a \hat b ^\dagger) $$

($\hbar=1$.)

I first tried deriving the energy eigenstates but needed an initial condition which I am not aware of, am I right to assume that $\|\psi(0)\rangle = |n, n-1>$  or similar?

Answer (score 2):

Try and find  combinations
$$
\hat c_i = u_i \hat a +v_i \hat  b,\quad  \\
\hat c^\dagger_i = u^*_i \hat a^\dagger  +v^*_i \hat  b^\dagger
$$ for $i=1,2$ that

1. preserve the commutation relations  $[\hat c_i,\hat c_j^\dagger]=\delta_{ij} $, $[\hat c_i,\hat c_j]=0$ etc
2. reduces $H$ to
   $$
   H= \omega_1 \hat c_1^\dagger \hat c_1+ \omega_2 \hat c_2^\dagger \hat c_2.
   $$

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious but I am not sure on the next step. It looks like the Hamiltonian has been reduced to a system which has no coupling in terms of the new redefined oscillators so would the eigenenergies be just that of two separate oscillators?

Comment: Yes:  $E_{n_1,n_2}=n_1 \omega+ n_2 \omega_2$.

Answer (score 0):

The [earlier answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/630582/291677) is great. Of note, this is the same method that you could use for figuring out the normal modes of two classical coupled operators.

So, an alternative method for solving this problem is to first find the normal modes of the classical coupled oscillators, then quantize the two modes. Essentially you will find the two frequencies $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ that [mike stone](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/80687/mike-stone) mentioned, and your two normal modes, when quantized, will be annihilated by $\hat{c}_1$ and $\hat{c}_2$.